# Automatically update and delete data into a table from a view without using triggers

Tags: sql-server

This is the rough table which also  has the unnecessary data:

```
id  name   dob      phone    update-date     location
1   ann   5/4/1995  574-81    8/7/2014       LA
2   joe   6/2/2000  547-98    10/8/2017      Canada
3   Tim   8/6/2010  654-890   4/5/2018       LA
```

Here I only want the fields such as id, name, dob and an extra column transformed from dob as age. my output table is:

```
id  name     dob      age
1   ann    5/4/1995   24
2   joe    6/2/2000   17
3   Tim    8/6/2010   7
```

the problem is: when updating the table with another 10 records the unnecessary columns does not appear and the age column will automatically update without using triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having another table, just create a view on top of your original table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT id, name, dob, DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, GETDATE()) AS age
FROM   my_table;
```

Comment: I want a new table based on the old one @Mureinik

Comment: Why would you need another table? Why isn't a view sufficient?

Comment: ok. then how to import the data to the new view automatically from another view? @Mureinik

Comment: @AnuAntony you don't need to import any data - a view is just a named query. Once you insert/update/delete from your original table, you can just query the view and you'll see the up-to-date data.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, GETDATE())` doesn't give you the same answer as a person would give if asked their age. It may overshoot by almost a year (e.g. `DATEDIFF(year,'20171231','20180101')` answers `1` when most people would state `0`). A more complex expression is required if the real age is desired.